# RecyclerView onInterceptTouchEvent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I want to add click listeners to items in my recylcerview. For example I want to open new activity on normal item click, and on long click i want to delete the item.

```
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onInterceptTouchEvent: called , MotionEvent = " + e.getActionIndex() + " ; " + e.getActionMasked());
        if (e.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "onInterceptTouchEvent: called = " + rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I tried this but it never gets to onTouchEvent() method.
This second log gives me good info about item position.

Comment: Set `OnClickListener` and `OnLongClickListener` in your child view inside the `onBindViewHolder` method.

Comment: Set `OnClickListener` and `OnLongClickListener` in your custom `ViewHolder`